# Can I set a process name for my tomcats on CentOS ?

Tags: linux, centos, process, bash-scripting, tomcat

I have several tomcats running on my centos.  If I try "top",  all of them are shown as  "java" .

Is there anyway, such as changing the catalin.sh, that I can make each of the tomcat has its own name ?

Answer (score 0):

The java executable is a binary, so it is not easy.  If it were one of certain script/interpreted languages (zsh, perl, etc.), then it would be a simple matter of changing the arg0 argument (e.g., `$0` in perl) in the script to be whatever you wanted.  You could do this to a binary, of course, but you'd have to recompile the code.

One way to get around that is by using the **procname** utility, which was made for exactly what you describe: changing the name of a java process.

https://github.com/electrum/procname

You'd have to do some hackery to get your tomcat start-up scripts to use this utility.